# on selecting radio button, div is not displaying in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have created a radio button such that when user click any button some content is displayed in a div.

i have done the following code for it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
    var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
    $(".box").not(targetBox).hide();
    $(targetBox).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.cheque {
  background: #ff0000;
}

.bank {
  background: #228B22;
}

.cash {
  background: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top: 1%;" class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">


    <div style="background-color: #f5f5f5; border-radius: 10px;" class="col-md-12 border-1px">


      <div class="payment-method">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="payment_type" value="bank">
                                  Direct Bank Transfer </label>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="payment_type" value="cheque">
                                  Cheque Payment </label>
            <p></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="payment_type" value="cash" checked="">
                                  Pay In Cash </label>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="bank box">Make your payment directly into our bank account. Please use your Order ID as the payment reference. Your order won’t be shipped until the funds have cleared in our account.</strong> so i am here</div>
      <div class="cheque box">Please send your cheque to Store Name, Store Street, Store Town, Store State / County, Store Postcode.</div>
      <div class="cash box">Please use your Order ID as the payment reference. Your order won’t be shipped until the funds have cleared in our account.</div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
i have tried adding 

> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

but no use
```

but when i select any radio button nothing is happening. can anyone please tell me what is wrong in my code. thanks in advance

Comment: the example you have works just fine for me

Comment: I can see that the divs are being hidden properly

Comment: but for me its not working

Comment: @Ramesh but when i select dropdown its not appearing

Comment: @kingkhankkhan I don't see a dropdown element in your question

Comment: @Ramesh sorry, i meant radio button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are only missing the default show for the cash the rest is working fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".cash").show();
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
    var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
    $(".box").not(targetBox).hide();
    $(targetBox).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.cheque {
  background: #ff0000;
}

.bank {
  background: #228B22;
}

.cash {
  background: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin-top: 1%;" class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">


    <div style="background-color: #f5f5f5; border-radius: 10px;" class="col-md-12 border-1px">


      <div class="payment-method">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="payment_type" value="bank">
                                  Direct Bank Transfer </label>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="payment_type" value="cheque">
                                  Cheque Payment </label>
            <p></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="payment_type" value="cash" checked="">
                                  Pay In Cash </label>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="bank box">Make your payment directly into our bank account. Please use your Order ID as the payment reference. Your order won’t be shipped until the funds have cleared in our account.</strong> so i am here</div>
      <div class="cheque box">Please send your cheque to Store Name, Store Street, Store Town, Store State / County, Store Postcode.</div>
      <div class="cash box">Please use your Order ID as the payment reference. Your order won’t be shipped until the funds have cleared in our account.</div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> [image: Upvote if you like it]

Comment: i didnt understand, what did i miss?

Comment: on page load you are selecting `cash` as your default selection and only showing the div content on click, so you have to trigger the show for the default on page load

Comment: which browser do you use ?

Comment: the console is showing Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined